# How can I use JavaScript setTimeout in p5.js to illustrate a merge sort?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, settimeout, mergesort, p5.js

I created a JavaScript & p5.js illustration for a merge sort. It works perfectly, all that I want is to make it sort at given time intervals. Where do I need to put the setTimeout or setInterval function, in order to show the numbers sort at 500ms interval? This is my p5 editor link: https://editor.p5js.org/alexrotariu/sketches/m4AFV21qJ

```
numbers = [15, 20, 4, 1, 25, 45, 32, 4];

function doMergeSort() {
    numbers = mergeSort(numbers);
}

function mergeSort(array) {
    if (array.length < 2) {
        return array;
    }
    let middle = parseInt(array.length/2);
    let left = array.slice(0, middle);
    let right = array.slice(middle, array.length);
    return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right))
}

function merge(left, right) {
    let result = [];
    while (left.length && right.length) {
        if (left[0] <= right[0]) {
            result.push(left.shift());
        } else {
            result.push(right.shift());            
        }
    }
    while (left.length) {
        result.push(left.shift());
    }
    while (right.length) {
        result.push(right.shift());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer fully I will need to see how you handle your draw method. Remember that he main loop of your application is in draw. This means that it will not change as methods are called in the draw loop, but only give you the results of everything at the end of draw and update the screen with that.

If you are calling doMergeSort() in the draw method, you will always be drawing the sorted array.

You will have to find some way to break up the merge sort algorithm so that each step is incremented by a loop through draw. This usually requires "breaking" the algorithm in sone way for the purpose of demonstrating it.

Here is a very simple example of the concept I am talking about:

Notice how circleB doesnt update for every iteration of the UpdateCircleB() for loop, it only updates once the end of Draw() is reached.

```js
let circleA = {
  y : 50,
  x : 30,
  r : 50

}

let circleB = {
  y : 150,
  x : 30,
  r : 50
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 200);
}

function draw() {
  //Increment Purple circle using draw loop
  //Every time we draw a frame, we move circle A 1 pixel to the right
  circleA.x++;
  
  //The green circle uses a for loop inside a method call to update
  //Every time we draw a frame, we move circle B 50 pixels to the right
  moveCircleB();
  
  //draw purple circle
  fill(152, 114, 132);
  ellipse(circleA.x,circleA.y,circleA.r);
  
  //draw green circle
  fill(157, 191, 158);
  ellipse(circleB.x,circleB.y,circleB.r);
}

function moveCircleB(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    circleB.x++;
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```